# ActiveX Word Control in asp Web page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Im trying to use word control at my Web page. There's sample of code :

JS:

```
function fopendocument() {
    try {
        getradiovalue();
        if (obj == null) {
            obj = document.ControlWordExcelObj;
        }
        if (obj) {
            var vfilename = obj.BrowseFileDialog(vapptype);
        }
    } catch (ex) {
        alert(ex);
    }
}
```

ASPX:

C#:

```
public void OpenDocument(string sMyFileName,string sAppType)
        {
            sFileName = sMyFileName;

            //object for word
            if (acWord == null && sAppType=="W") { acWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass(); }
            //object for excel
            if (acExcel == null && sAppType == "E") { acExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass(); }

            if (wDocument != null) { try { CloseAndSave(sAppType); } catch { } }

            if (eWorkBook != null) { try { CloseAndSave(sAppType); } catch { } }
            // "Opusapp" for ms word.
            if (iWindow == 0 && sAppType == "W") { iWindow = FindWindow("Opusapp", null); }
            // "XLMAIN" for ms excel.
            if (iWindow == 0 && sAppType == "E") { iWindow = FindWindow("XLMAIN",null); }

            if (iWindow != 0)
            {
                //call SetParent function.
                SetParent(iWindow, this.Handle.ToInt32());

                object oFileName = sFileName;
                object oReadOnly = false;
                object oIsVisible = true;
                object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

                try
                {
                    if (iWindow == 0) { throw new Exception(); }
                    //object for word
                    if (sAppType == "W")
                    {
                        if (acWord.Documents == null && sAppType == "W") { throw new Exception(); }

                        if (acWord != null && acWord.Documents != null && sAppType == "W")
                        { wDocument = acWord.Documents.Open(ref oFileName, ref oMissing, ref oReadOnly, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, 
                            ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oIsVisible, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, 
                            ref oMissing, ref oMissing); }

                        if (wDocument == null && sAppType == "W") { throw new Exception(); }
                    }
                    //object for excel
                    if (sAppType == "E")
                    {
                        if (acExcel.Workbooks == null && sAppType == "E") { throw new Exception(); }

                        if (acExcel != null && acExcel.Workbooks != null && sAppType == "E")
                        { eWorkBook = acExcel.Workbooks.Open(sFileName, oMissing, oReadOnly, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, 
                            oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing); }

                        if (eWorkBook == null && sAppType == "E") { throw new Exception(); }
                    }
                }
                catch { }
                try
                {
                    //object for word
                    if (sAppType == "W")
                    {
                        acWord.Visible = true;
                        acWord.Activate();                        
                    }
                    //object for excel
                    if (sAppType == "E")
                    {
                        acExcel.Visible = true;
                        acExcel.UserControl = true;
                    }
                    // call SetWindowPos
                    SetWindowPos(iWindow, this.Handle.ToInt32(), 0, 0, this.Bounds.Width, this.Bounds.Height, (0x4 | 0x2 | 0x20));

                    OnResize(new EventArgs());

                }
                catch { MessageBox.Show("Error..."); }
                this.Parent.Focus();
            }

        }
```

Its example downloaded from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/404688/Word-Excel-ActiveX-Controls-in-ASP-NET

When i click at Open docs button im getting exception :

TypeError: Undefined is not a function. 
Problematic line : 
var vfilename = obj.BrowseFileDialog(vapptype);

what's wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

try checking for obj == undefined instead of obj == null.

Before proceeding, make sure that wherever you host this application will have the Office suite installed on it. If they aren't installed on the server then this cannot work since you cannot use the Interop libraries as all they are is a bridge between your code and the MS Office applications. Microsoft has recommended against using the Office applications in a web server environment since the late 90's. The threading models of the applications were never meant to be used within an environment such as a web server and thus create instability on the server.

The code samples you are referencing also use a number of dllimport calls. Between that and usage of the interop libraries you will need highly elevated permissions for the application to run in, which will be very difficult to setup correctly and will be denied by most hosting companies unless you are using fully dedicated servers under your control

If you must communicate with Office documents from the server side, look for a managed code library such as the OpenXML SDK which can work with [Office 2007](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854%28v=office.15%29.aspx) and later file formats.

Comment: i need open/edit and save doc on webpage and make list of modificated files ( sth like web repository for docs)  function fopendocument() {
    try {
        getradiovalue();
        obj = document.ControlWordExcelObj;
        var vfilename = obj.BrowseFileDialog(vapptype);
    } catch (ex) {
        alert(ex);
    }
} is not working too ;(

Comment: I misread the gist of the article. I didn't realize it was attempting to make a full wrapper around word and excel. So to re-iterate, you are testing this with IE correct? It won't run on any other browser. Next, you have successfully installed the ActiveX control on your computer correct? Did you also read through some of the comments? There appear to be code change recommendations since the article was first written that may address the issue.